# How to sort python dictionary/list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

How would you print this list

```
cat1 = {"sam":[4,9,7], "jeff":[3,3,6], "ben":[9,8,6]}
```

in alphabetical order with the highest number for each person, by the highest number of each person in descending order and by the average score of each person in descending order?
Ive looked into using class1.values() but this only prints all the values where do i go from here to sorting them?

Comment: You'll get more and better answers if you show us an example of what you have tried yourself

Comment: I'm unsure whether to look into list or dictionary sorting

Comment: You're using dictionaries and lists, so [both](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently unsorted. You cannot sort a ``dict`` without first translating it into a list of key/value pairs then sorting **that** list.

Comment: how would i translate it?

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted, but you can iterate through them in a sorted fashion, which generally suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question, these should do it:

```
for person in sorted(cat1):
    print(person, max(cat1.get(person)))
```

result:

```
ben 9
jeff 6
sam 9
```

then:

```
for person in sorted(cat1, key=lambda x: max(cat1.get(x)), reverse=True):
    print(person, max(cat1.get(person)))
```

result:

```
ben 9
sam 9
jeff 6
```

then:

```
for person in sorted(cat1, key=lambda x: sum(cat1.get(x))/len(cat1.get(x)), reverse=True):
    print(person, sum(cat1.get(person))/len(cat1.get(person)))
```

result:

```
ben 7.666666666666667
sam 6.666666666666667
jeff 4.0
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can also upvote/accept to indicate that this was a useful answer.